# Multiple page publishing in SDL Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

How can I publish a page to more than one child publication at a time using the SDL Tridion 2009 GUI?

Here is an example of what I want to achieve: I have a Publication called "Global" with a Page called home.aspx  and then two child Publications (UK and USA). I want to publish both child home.aspx pages at the same time, is it possible?

Answer (score 7):

You'd need to associate your parent (Global) publication to the publication target that the children pages need to publish too.

this unfortunately means your 'global' page will also publish to the server.   You could write a **custom resolver** around this to remove the page from the published zip package, but this will require some development work to implement.

Bart Koopman has written a post which explains how you can do this here : http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/no-faking-publish-from-a-parent-publication-without-faking-a-publication-target

Answer (score 4):

To publish pages in child publications by selecting publishing of a master page you could employ the event system.  Since you're on Tridion 2009 you will need to use the COM+ event system (can't use the new TOM.NET one).

The logic should be as follows:
You may want to put a publication metadata schema on the parent publication that will specify the IDs of the child publications that this cascaded publishing should work for (or create a configuration component).  You will also need to specify which publication targets you'll want to publish to for the child publications.

In OnPublishPre (or Post) event use the TOM API to get Pages in the child publications and do page.Publish().

The advantage here is that content managers/publishers don't need to worry about having to go into the Advanced tab and select additional options.

Answer (score 3):

If  you want to publish the same page in multiple child publications, click on the advanced tab of the publish dialog, and check the *"also publish in child publications"* check box.

There is more information on this approach in this post http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/no-faking-publish-from-a-parent-publication-without-faking-a-publication-target.

Depending on whether your parent publication should actually be published, you may want to consider one of the *Custom Resolver* or *Event System* solutions offered by John Winter or Nickoli Roussakov in the other answers on this page.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I want to publish the same page under two different child publications. In example I have a Global publication with a home.aspx page and then two child publications, Uk and USA, and I want to publish home.aspx for these two at the same time, is it possible?

Comment: Also see ways to avoid pushing parent items in Bart's comment to this TridionDeveloper.com post: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/no-faking-publish-from-a-parent-publication-without-faking-a-publication-target

Comment: I have updated my answer, perhaps you can update your question also - it will help others with the same problem. Please also consider committing to the SDL Tridion proposal on Area 51 using your SO login at: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2